# Adding multiple images to a html file using Jinja2

Tags: html, python-3.x, image, templates, jinja2

I am trying to load and add multiple figures from disk to a HTML file

For adding a single image, I tried the following (ref.: [Jinja2/Python insert a image(s) into html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855777/jinja2-python-insert-a-images-into-html))

```
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('.'),
        trim_blocks=True,
        lstrip_blocks=True,
    )

template = env.get_template("template.html")
template_vars = {"title":"TITLE", "graph":'obj.png'}

text = template.render(template_vars)
with open("test2.html", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(text)
```

The template looks like the below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Graph Goes Here</h2>
<img src="obj.png">
</body>
</html>
```

To extend this to add multiple images, I made the following modification in the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Graph Goes Here</h2>
<dl>
{% for key, value in template_vars.items() %}
 <img src="{{value}}.png">
{% endfor %}
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how

```
template_vars = {"title":"TITLE", "graph":'obj.png'}
```

has to be modified to pass multiple figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update the object type used for your variable `template_vars` to make things simpler to iterate. Instead of a dictionary, you likely want a **list of dictionaries** so that you will be able to loop over each image and get multiple attributes for each one (in your case, a value for the key `title` and another one for the key `graph`). You should also refer to your variable when calling `template.render` so that Jinja2 knows what you are writing about (i.e., replace `template.render(template_vars)` with `template.render(template_vars=template_vars)`).

Your updated template might look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Graph Goes Here</h2>
    <dl>
        {% for image in template_vars %}
        <dt>{{ image.title }}</dt>
        <dd><img title="{{ image.title }}" src="{{ image.graph }}"></dd>
        {% endfor %}
    </dl>
</body>

</html>
```

Then, the part of your Python code that needs to be changed would look as follows:

```py
template_vars = [
    {"title": "TITLE", "graph": "obj.jpg"},
    {"title": "TITLE2", "graph": "obj2.jpg"},
]

text = template.render(template_vars=template_vars)
```

This will result in the following HTML source output:

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Graph Goes Here</h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>TITLE</dt>
        <dd><img title="TITLE" src="obj.jpg"></dd>
        <dt>TITLE2</dt>
        <dd><img title="TITLE2" src="obj2.jpg"></dd>
    </dl>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The solution posted works great! Thanks a lot. Could you please give some suggestions on how the template has to be modified to include two figures side by side i.e. 2 columns?

Comment: That should be a separate question as per the Stack Overflow customs since this is more about CSS than anything else. Nevertheless, I think a good place to start would be with Flexbox. Great resources for this might include the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/). Else you can keep things simpler, search for keywords like these: `html two columns layout`. You would only need to edit a bit your template inside the `<dl>` tag (and use some other tag instead, like `<div>`).