# Convert a html with images to pdf

Tags: html, python-3.x, pdf, xhtml2pdf, python-pdfkit

This is a follow up to my previous question
[Adding multiple images to a html file using Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834890/adding-multiple-images-to-a-html-file-using-jinja2)

I am trying to save the html created using `jinja2` to pdf.

```
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('.'),
        trim_blocks=True,
        lstrip_blocks=True,
    )

template = env.get_template("template.html")
template_vars = [
 {"title": "TITLE", "graph": "obj.jpg"},
 {"title": "TITLE2", "graph": "obj2.jpg"},
]
#template_vars = {"title":"TITLE", "graph":'obj.png'}

text = template.render(template_vars)
with open("test.html", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(text)
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Graph Goes Here</h2>
    <dl>
        {% for image in template_vars %}
        <dt>{{ image.title }}</dt>
        <dd><img title="{{ image.title }}" src="{{ image.graph }}"></dd>
        {% endfor %}
    </dl>
</body>

</html>
```

To convert the html created in the above code, I tried to use `pdfkit`

```
 pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'test.pdf')
```

But this didn't work for me; I get the following error

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\envs\pancreas_model\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 155, in handle_error
    raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

I also tried `xhtml2pdf` and this fails due to the image paths

```
with open('test.pdf', "w+b") as f_out:
    pisa.CreatePDF(
        src=text,  # HTML to convert
        dest=f_out)
```

WARNING:xhtml2pdf:Need a valid file name!
''

Could someone please suggest how to convert the html with multiple images to pdf?
I am not sure if I have to specify a template for the pdf output like the one specified
for html.

EDIT:

The relative path is specified in the template in the following line

```
<dd><img title="{{ image.title }}" src="./{{ image.graph }}"></dd>
```

Comment: Your `template_vars` is a single `object`-type variable, but your template assumes it's an array-type, which it isn't.

Comment: @Dai Please check my edit.  I've modified `template_vars`

Comment: Have you tried passing relative paths to images to the html and run `xhtml2pdf` on it? `obj.jpg` => `./obj.jpg`. Also, make sure the images are in the same directory as the html file.

Comment: @MaciejGol Thanks for the reply. Yes, the relative path is specified in the template file. Please check my edit. There is no issue while creating the html, the images are read from the path and displayed correctly. The problem is when I convert the html to pdf.

Comment: @Natasha You need to change those `<img src=""` URIs to be **absolute URIs** (with a leading `http`/`https` URI scheme, `file:` might even work too, YMMV). This is because all these Chromium-based HTML-to-PDF generators (invariably just some repackaged build of `QtWebEngine`, in my experience) feed the HTML in some kind of isolated environment where relative-paths can't resolve to anything.

Comment: @Dai Thanks a lot, Could you please share an example of how the absolute URI should look like? I have the images in my folder and I have the absolute paths. I am not sure how to specify the absolute URIs for the local paths since these images are not uploaded anywhere.

Comment: If the images are small (say, all under 10KB) you could use a `data:` URI. Otherwise you’ll need to run a webserver to serve the images from a `http://localhost:12345/` address, I guess.